# Unexplainable LLVM vs GCC OpenMP differences

Tags: gcc, openmp

Consider the following matrix multiplication code:

```
#define BLOCKING 64
void mat_mult_ijk_blocked(
          const int m,
              const int n,
              const int p,
              real a[restrict m][p],
              const real b[m][n],
              const real c[n][p]) {
  for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for(int k=0; k<p; k++) {
      a[i][k] = 0.0;
    }
  }
#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int block_i=0; block_i<m; block_i += BLOCKING) {
    for(int block_j=0; block_j<n; block_j += BLOCKING) {
      for(int i=block_i; i<min(block_i + BLOCKING, m); i++) {
        for(int j=block_j; j<min(block_j + BLOCKING, n); j++) {
          real w = b[i][j];
          for(int k=0; k<p; k++) {
            a[i][k] += w * c[j][k];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For 1800×2200×1400 multiplication:

- With clang without -fopenmp, the code takes 3.2s on my machine.
- With -fopenmp and

  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 1.6s
  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=3 2.1s
  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 1.6s
  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 2.6s

This machine has 2 cores with hyperthreading, this seems kind of reasonable.

Now with gcc-5.4.0:

- without -fopenmp 2.8s
- with -fopenmp

  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 5.1s
  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=3 4.6s
  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 4.9s
  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 10s

What am I doing wrong that gives so poor performance with gcc!?
The performance with a single thread of OpenMP is considerably worse than that of the original single-threaded code.

UPDATE - with gcc-6.2

- without -fopenmp 3.s
- with -fopenmp

  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 2.23s
  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=3 1.89s
  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 1.61s
  - OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 2.9s

Clearly now results are similar to those in LLVM. What is the reason for this?

Comment: You're asking us to guess what you probably know or could easily find out?  Maybe you're running on a dual core hyperthreaded platform and turned on auto-vectorization in some but not all cases.  I guess real is aliased to float.

Comment: I'm asking about single-threaded performance.